# jQuery on remove not working parent node fire empty()

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery ajax. According to the answer I remove or add. But jQuery.on function not working.

Example:

```
<div id="selector">
    <span>Hello World</span>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('remove','span',function(){
        alert(" first object object deleted");
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#selector').empty();
    },3000);
});
```

jsFiddle.net
https://jsfiddle.net/1zuau1f6/5/

edit: my question is not understood. Question I am correcting..

---Update---

i find solution in jquery.ui framework

```
$.cleanData = ( function( orig ) {
    return function( elems ) {
        var events, elem, i;
        for ( i = 0; ( elem = elems[ i ] ) != null; i++ ) {
            try {

                // Only trigger remove when necessary to save time
                events = $._data( elem, "events" );
                if ( events && events.remove ) {
                    $( elem ).triggerHandler( "remove" );
                }

                // Http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8235
            } catch ( e ) {}
        }
        orig( elems );
    };
} )( $.cleanData );
```

Comment: There is no `remove` event, hence why it's not working. If you want to run a code block on the removal of a DOMElement you would need to call it manually.

Comment: remove is not event in jquery

Comment: I edited your jsFiddle, it works now.

Comment: i usually $('#selector').parent().empty(). But remove event not working...

Comment: why this was voted down, it's a quality question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1) You have to include jquery UI library to use `remove` event.

2) event delegation does not work with `remove`. thus use:

```
$('div').on('remove',function(){
    alert(" first object object deleted");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ahtdutn/)**

Comment: @AhbapAldirmaz: sorry....
i didn't get you..

Answer (score 1):

give a try like this..

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#selector').trigger('remove').remove();       
},3000);
```

[fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bharathi038/1zuau1f6/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('remove','div',function(){
    alert("Element was removed");
   });     
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#selector').trigger('remove');
   },3000);
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/gayanstar/1zuau1f6/4/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Also you can override jQuery.remove() function:

```
$(function(){
    var origRemove = $.fn.remove;

    $.fn.remove = function newRemove() {
        var jQ = this.trigger("remove");
        return origRemove.apply(jQ, arguments);
    };    

    $(document).on('remove','div',function(){
        alert("object gonna be deleted");
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#selector').remove();        
    },3000);
})
```