# DevExtreme DataGrid onRowDblClick

Tags: javascript, datagrid, devexpress, devextreme

I want to implement an onRowDblClick event for the DevExtreme DataGrid.
I need this Event for multiple grids so I would like to implement this for the DataGrid for general.

I was thinking about overriding the onClick action and check for a double click or extend the DataGrid with an onRowDblClick Action but i have no idea how to implement this.

Please advise a way to do this functionality.

---

OK, finally I implemented an addRowDblClick function which looks like this:

```
var clickTimer, lastRowClickedId;
function addRowDblClick(id, dblClickFunc) {
  $("#" + id).dxDataGrid({
    onRowClick: function (e) {
      //OBTAIN YOUR GRID DATA HERE
      var grid = $("#" + id).dxDataGrid('instance');
      var rows = grid.getSelectedRowsData();

      if (clickTimer && lastRowCLickedId === e.rowIndex) {
        clearTimeout(clickTimer);
        clickTimer = null;
        lastRowCLickedId = e.rowIndex;
        //YOUR DOUBLE CLICK EVENT HERE
        if (typeof dblClickFunc == 'function')
          dblClickFunc();
      } else {
        clickTimer = setTimeout(function () { }, 250);
      }
      lastRowCLickedId = e.rowIndex;
    }
  });
}
```

And at the DataGrid I called an function OnContentReady where I call this function with the Id and the function I want to call when I double click.

```
addRowDblClick('dxDataGrid', showDetail);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and worked pretty well (I followed [this answer](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T143438/dxdatagrid-provide-the-row-double-click-event))

```
var clickTimer, lastRowCLickedId;

    $("#grdMain").dxDataGrid({            
        ...
        onRowClick: function (e) {               
            //OBTAIN YOUR GRID DATA HERE
              var grid = $("#grdMain").dxDataGrid('instance');
              var rows = grid.getSelectedRowsData();

            if (clickTimer && lastRowCLickedId === e.rowIndex) {
                clearTimeout(clickTimer);
                clickTimer = null;
                lastRowCLickedId = e.rowIndex;
                //YOUR DOUBLE CLICK EVENT HERE
                alert('double clicked!');
            } else {
                clickTimer = setTimeout(function () { }, 250);
            }

            lastRowCLickedId = e.rowIndex;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you did this for every grid? I need a global implementation because i need the onRowDblClick event for 15 grids. Thats why i want to extend the DataGrid. But I dont know how.

Comment: @Ich yes I actually followed the answer from DX

Answer (score 1):

I that work with this :

```
$("#grdMain").dxDataGrid({
   ....
   onRowPrepared:function(event){
      $(event.rowElement).on('dblclick', function(){
         console.log('row dblclicked');
      }).on('remove', function(){
          //on remove event in jquery ui libraries or 
          // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255801/jquery-on-remove-not-working-parent-node-fire-empty
          $(this).off('dblclick remove');
     })
  }            
})
```